# I want to render html I read from the DB and display the result, instead of the actual html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

I'm using a ckeditor in my intranet.
I use it to save formated text, like links, for example.

The thing is, what I have in the ckeditor source is

```
<p>
this is the new <a href="http://www.google.com">test</a> we need to run.</p>
```

and what I see in the editor is

```
test(as a link)
```

What gets saved in the DB is

```
 &lt;p&gt;
    this is the new &lt;a href="http://www.google.com"&gt;test&lt;/a&gt; we need to run.&lt;/p&gt;
```

which is correct.

But when I want to edit it on ckeditor, what I see is

```
<p> <a href="http://www.google.com">test</a></p>
```

and what I see as source is

```
&lt;p&gt;
        &lt;a href="http://www.google.com"&gt;test&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

I would like to see exactly the same when I edit it.

Anoter thing is, I'm using Html.Raw to display it in my index, but it shows me the html. I would like to see the rendered html.

So, if I save

```
<p>
    this is the new <a href="http://www.google.com">test</a> we need to run.</p>
```

I want to see

```
this is the new test(as link) we need to run
```

and not

```
<p>
        this is the new <a href="http://www.google.com">test</a> we need to run.</p>
```

Any ideas??
Rui Martins

Comment: Looks like you are HTML Encoding the value from CKEditor before it gets to the database... CKEditor will not do that itself, so it must be somewhere in your code

Comment: need to html decode your results

Comment: Where is your markup that displays the html from your database?

Comment: @McMastermind - as he actually wants the HTML to be displayed, I would suggest that it would be better to **not** HTML Encode it in the first place, rather than HTML Decode it afterwards

Comment: Rui - I notice in your question you state that the HTML encoded string stored in the database "is correct".  If you really want the HTML encoded string to be stored, then @McMastermind is indeed correct in stating that you need to HTML Decode before displaying

Comment: I decoded the html and it worked. Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are the not understanding of htmlentities.

### Encoding HTML

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

### Decoding HTML

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

### Example usage both

```
<?php

   $orig = "I'll \"walk\" the <b>dog</b> now";

   $a = htmlentities($orig);
   $b = html_entity_decode($a);

   echo $a; // I'll &quot;walk&quot; the &lt;b&gt;dog&lt;/b&gt; now
   echo $b; // I'll "walk" the <b>dog</b> now

?>
```

## Edit (Added asp.net equivalent)

```
Server.HtmlEncode("<your string>");

Server.HtmlDecode("&lt;your string&gt;");
```

Comment: You are correct, but an ASP.NET set of examples might have been more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<%: Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(YourHTMLStringHere)) %>
```

It will just render the HTML code